# What does the "Darsana Global" event mean?

Tags: ingress

I've missed the opportunity to follow the first septicycle (Shaper Septicycle 2014.42) batch of Darsana events. I've only attended to one of my local satellite cities but didn't know the calculation details of Darsana series. Now the second septicycle (2014.43) is on the run and apart from the first one, it only has one primary and 3 satellites for 15.11.2014 but there is one catch: They've listed a global event for the same day on their event site: https://www.ingress.com/events

What is this "global" event? Is it just an abbreviation for the global satellite cities (The list for the 2014.43 septicycle on the "details" frame on this page: https://plus.google.com/events/ci263osd1ms3ml31gjmg2u99h8s), or is this something completely different? Was there something similar for the first Darsana septicycle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Global" event was two sets of 50 cells whose cell scores counted towards the faction scores in the Anomaly series.